# How can you get the workspace if there is a space in the folder in jenkins declarative pipeline ]?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am still pretty new to jenkins, and I was working on a pipeline and the workspace path goes as follows:
workspace/folder withspace/Pipeline. I am trying to give jenkins permissions to run a bash script, but because of the space in the folder name I get the error:

```
chmod: cannot access /workspace/folder’: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘withspace/Pipeline’: No such file or directory.
```

I realize that getting rid of the space in the folder name would fix the problem, but I was asked to fix this problem without removing the space. [Here are the lines in my code causing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofrfx.png) Thank you for any suggestion and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash you can either use quotation marks to enclose the entire path, or use a backslash to escape each space character.
In your case because you don't control the value, you need to quote the workspace path:

```
sh "chmod +x -R \"${env.WORKSPACE}\""
```